# Disable plugin on Specific Page of Admin

Tags: plugins

I have 2 plugins

1) FAT Gallery

2) Salon Booking

So FAT Gallery has a certain js lib (select2) which conflicts with Salon Booking Settings page.

In this URL

```
example.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=sln_booking
```

I'm trying to `DISABLE` the FAT Gallery because it causes js error and i cant do my job.

Any idea of how to block it ONLY on the certain page?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty easy.

Remember, I don't know exactly what's the plugin's file name and directory, and the following code was not tested.

Put this to the `functions.php` or create a small plugin.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'wpse264498_deactivate_fat_gallery' );

function wpse264498_deactivate_fat_gallery($plugins){

    // check if you are on the certain page
    global $pagenow;
    if( $pagenow == 'post-new.php' ) {

        // check if it's right CPT
        if( isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'sln_booking') {

            // search the plugin to disable among active plugins
            // Warning! Check the plugin directory and name
            $key = array_search( 'fat-gallery/fat-gallery.php' , $plugins );

            // if found, unset it from the active plugins array
            if ( false !== $key ) {
                unset( $plugins[$key] );
            }
        }
    }

    return $plugins;
}
```

Also, you can try [Plugin Organizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-organizer/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! in your example, what should i check to be compatible? only `$key = array_search( 'fat-gallery/fat-gallery.php' , $plugins );` ?

Comment: it's working :D

Answer (score 1):

I have tested [Plugin Organizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-organizer/) but I found it difficult to use.

In replacement I found [Freesoul Deactivate Plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/freesoul-deactivate-plugins/) which have a really nice and simple UI and works perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.
This does not deactivate the whole plugin but just remove the script that causes problems.
Not tested, look the functions up if you don´t know how to use them and what parameters to use.

```
// add this hook if in admin area
if (is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_dequeue_script", 99);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   // don´t do it if it´s not the page you want to remove the script
   if (get_current_screen() != "yourpage") return;
   // deregister the script
   // find the exact name of the script in the plugin where it is registered
   wp_deregister_script('fatgalleryScript');

}
```